# How to print something on every page on page.pdf

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to setup an anchor tag on every page. Is that possible?

```
<a href='#toc'>toc</a>
```

I tried implementing it like this

```
   async function printPDF(domain,filename){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 600, height: 400 })
    await page.goto(domain + '/docs/' + filename + '.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    const pdf = await page.pdf({ 
        format: 'A4',
        scale : 1,
        printBackground : true,
        headerTemplate: "<a href='#toc'>toc</a>" ,
        displayHeaderFooter : true,
        margin: { top: "2cm", bottom: "2cm", left: "2cm", right: "2cm" }
    });
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
}
```

But it's not working. Maybe because the header is treated as seperate from the content so it's not detecting the anchor?